# 'Forbidden you don't have permissions to access on server...' from remote compute and yet working on localhost

Tags: apache, web-services

I am getting the following error when i try to access a file via apache server at a url

Forbidden you don't have permissions to access on server.

I have changed the directory settings to the following and restarted the server.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Note: My instance was installed as part of WAMP package and i am on a win10 machine, local.

Any ideas what this could be? File permissions at OS level?

Update: i can hit the url of file from local browser but not remotely eg from mobile phone.

Comment: That is not the full error message you get. Something is missing. Please post the _full_ error message you get.

Comment: Apart from that: your host configuration specifically _denies_ _all access_ to _everything_: `Deny from all`

Comment: Not much more....Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /dir/image.png on this server. Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at 192.168.1.29 Port 8082

Comment: Which _is_ something different, isn't it? Why do you think posting _parts_ of an error message is a good idea? Apart from this: I think my last comment answers your question.

Comment: If it is Apache 2.4+, you should be using `Require all granted` instead of `Deny/allow` directives. As to the question, @arkascha 's 2nd comment is all that is needed.

Comment: updated question: i see that my local works but not from mobile which may be confusing some of my troubleshooting. is there a setting which allows remote access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was complicated by fact that after apache 3 you dont need to change the 'httpd.conf' to solve this issue but go to httpd.vhosts.conf and change 'Require Local' to 'Require all granted' to allow remote access as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I moved to Vultr as my new VPS from VPSie with a Ubuntu 18 setup. I'd my webroot in my $HOME/www directory. It's not a production system, just for my development purposes.

I edited the apache2.conf file and added the following. After restarting Apache it fixed the issue.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /home/YourUserName/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Replace "/home/YourUserName/www/" with your own directory. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

goto apache(in taskbar)/httpd.vhosts.con

```
<Directory "e:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    require all granted
</Directory>
```

and restart the wampserver